# I need a faster way with logging function to parse this special type of data in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a file with below data format

```
<aqr>a=769 b="United States" c=02/04/2019 d=01:03:23
<aqr>a=798 b="India" c=02/04/2019 d=01:03:23 e="Non existent"
```

So basically all the lines have multiple columns but the columns are not fixed and no header is there. So need to create column header from the data itself. Like for the example above a,b,c,d and e will be column header.

I have made a code which does the job but I am looking for a more faster way and with logging facility.

By far my logic is to remove unwanted data at the beginning, then get the data in a dictionary and turn it into a dataframe.

```py
result = defaultdict(list)
with open('testfiles/test.csv', 'r') as file:
    pardic = { }
    new_list = []
    final_list = []
    for line in file.read().splitlines():
        rule0 = line.strip("<aqr>")
        rule0 = '~'.join(shlex.split(rule0))
        y = rule0.split('~')
        for word in y:
            x = word.split('=')
            result[x[0]].append(x[1])
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
data = data.T
```

The result is fine. I just need a faster solution to this.

Comment: `rule0 = '~'.join(shlex.split(rule0)); y = rule0.split('~')` seems kind of redundant at first glance; what is the reason you do it this way, and not just `y = shlex.split(rule0)`?

Comment: Yes you were right. There was no need for that.